# Cherokee : force http over to https error

Tags: https, ubuntu-9.10, cherokee

I'm trying to get Cherokee to force all http:// over to https:// for one of my virtual servers.

Right now I've used the configuration suggested at the [cookbook](http://www.cherokee-project.com/doc/cookbook_http_to_https.html).

Here is the part in the /etc/cherokee/cherokee.conf

> vserver!30!rule!700!handler = redir
>
> vserver!30!rule!700!handler!rewrite!1!regex = ^/(.*)$
>
> vserver!30!rule!700!handler!rewrite!1!show = 1
>
> vserver!30!rule!700!handler!rewrite!1!substring = https://${host}/$1
>
> vserver!30!rule!700!match = not
>
> vserver!30!rule!700!match!final = 1
>
> vserver!30!rule!700!match!right = tls
>
> vserver!30!rule!700!only_secure = 0

All I get is a blank page.

I did some tailing of /var/log/cherokee/cherokee.error and realized that it writes the following error:

> {'type': "critical", 'time': "26/10/2010 22:18:28.782", 'title': "Could not execute the Panic handler: '/usr/share/cherokee/cherokee-panic 16587', status 255", 'code': "server.c:1854", 'error': "137", 'description': "Something happened with the server, and it felt panic. It tried to call an external program to report it to the administrator, but it failed.", 'version': "1.0.8", 'compilation_date': "Aug 11 2010 22:26:42", 'configure_args': " '--host=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--enable-os-string=Ubuntu' '--enable-pthreads' '--prefix=/usr' '--localstatedir=/var' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--docdir=/usr/share/doc/cherokee-doc' '--with-wwwroot=/var/www' '--with-included-gettext' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-Wall -g -O2' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions' 'CPPFLAGS=' '--host=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--enable-os-string=Ubuntu' '--enable-pthreads' '--prefix=/usr' '--localstatedir=/var' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--docdir=/usr/share/doc/cherokee-doc' '--with-wwwroot=/var/www' '--with-included-gettext' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-Wall -g -O2' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions' 'CPPFLAGS='", 'backtrace': ""}

Anyone got an idea to where I should be looking? I'll gladly post more debug info!

-víðir

Answer (score 0):

Try configure Cherokee via his web interface. It is easy and recommended.

Comment: That's what I've done ;) I just pasted the content of the configuration file for debugging purposes :)